# traslate query "delete join" from postgres to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, using

Hallo to everyone and thanks for the attention.I have to "traslate" from postgres to oracle this "delete join query"

```
DELETE FROM AAA USING BBB WHERE (AAA.date = BBB.date)
 AND (AAA.idtipo = BBB.idtipo)
 AND (AAA.tariffario = BBB.tariffario)
 AND (BBB.IDOrigine = 20 )
```

Thanks !!
Gian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
DELETE FROM AAA 
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM BBB
                 WHERE (AAA.date = BBB.date) AND
                       (AAA.idtipo = BBB.idtipo) AND
                       (AAA.tariffario = BBB.tariffario) AND
                       (BBB.IDOrigine = 20 )
                );
```

This is standard SQL and should work in both Postgres and Oracle (and other databases as well).